# reactjs - trying to add search/filter list error Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

New to react and trying to do it all on my own:

I understand the error and that the hook needs to be called from inside a function, but no idea how to fix the code so that the `grocery` input field can be made into a searchable field.

The error:

> Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { addGrocerySettings } from '../../actions/grocery_sett_list';
import MOCKDATA from '../../../../data1.json'


export class Grocery_Form extends Component {
  state = {
    grocery: '',
  }

  static propTypes = {
    addGrocerySettings: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };

  onChange = e => this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { grocery } = this.state;
    const grocery_sett_item = { grocery };
    this.props.addGrocerySettings(grocery_sett_item);
    this.setState({
      grocery: ''
    });
  };

  render() {
    
    const { grocery } = this.state;

    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('')

    return (
      <div className="card card-body mt-4 mb-4">
        <h2>Add Your Grocery Settings</h2>



        <div>

          <input type="text" placeholder="Search...." onChange={(event) =>{
            setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
          }} />
          {MOCKDATA.map((val, key)=>{
            return <div> { val.first_name } </div>;
          })}


        </div>



        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Grocery</label>
            <input className="form-control" type="text" name="grocery" 
            onChange={this.onChange}
            value={grocery}/>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}



export default connect(null, { addGrocerySettings })(Grocery_Form);
```

Comment: Which line throws the error? Also, you are mixing class components with functional components.

Comment: You are mixing hooks into a class component which is not possible with react. You need to first refactor everything to proper function components. BTW I recommend usiong the react beta docs, https://beta.reactjs.org/. The docs on the main site are annoyingly outdated -- no one really uses class components for new code.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski `const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('')` this line throws the error. I understand that I am mixing class and functional components. I am not sure how to fix this and still have a working page/form.

Comment: @AdamThomas should I be converting the class component to a functional one? I am very new to react and django. Just trying not to break something which is somewhat working if it can work.

Comment: Choose one type of component and stick to it. You should either use the state from the constructor or move to the functional component. Learn one technology at a time and make some research before asking the question.

Comment: @Sid just remove this line `const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('')`, and your code will work as exepected

Comment: It depends if this is new code. If its old legacy code, it might not be worth the cost of conversion. If you are just getting started, I would recommend switching rather than learning old ways.

Comment: I should stress your core problem can be solved in either type of component, so treat this as secondary advice.